# Scraping data from a website that make requests to others websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to see how this website [main url](https://www.betexplorer.com/football/argentina/primera-nacional/quilmes-brown-adrogue/Shg957JE/) take informations from this website [bookmaker url](https://www.pinnacle.com/en/soccer/argentina-primera-b-nacional/quilmes-vs-brown-de-adrogue/1575406434/). The goal should be get the bookmaker url by starting at main url.

[image]
Those are the data that I am looking for that should be come from bookmaker url. Now the question is, how the main url make a request to get those data?

I have used python `requests` on hidden url like [this](https://www.betexplorer.com/archive-odds/659nnxv464x0xgfn1h/18/) but it contains only an archive of the odds and seems it does not refer to the bookmaker url. I am just interested in getting the source of the data in the picture and get the url where its came from.

Comment: Actual URL for odds and bookmakers is [this](https://www.betexplorer.com/match-odds/Shg957JE/0/1x2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# The `Shg957JE` is taken from main URL
api_url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/match-odds/Shg957JE/0/1x2/'

data = requests.get(api_url).json()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data['odds'], 'html.parser')

for td in soup.select('td[data-odd]'):
    td.string = td['data-odd']

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0].iloc[:, [0, 4, 5, 6]][:-2]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Bookmakers: 14     1     X     2
0              10Bet  2.15  2.80  3.65
1              1xBet  2.16  3.04  3.80
2           888sport  2.20  2.88  3.60
3             bet365  2.25  2.90  3.60
4            Betfair  2.15  2.75  3.60
5            Betsafe  2.20  2.90  3.60
6            Betsson  2.20  2.90  3.60
7             Betway  2.15  2.80  3.60
8               bwin  2.15  2.87  3.50
9             ComeOn  2.10  2.80  3.60
10       Interwetten  2.15  2.80  3.60
11          Pinnacle  2.16  2.95  3.93
12      William Hill  2.20  2.90  3.40
13  Betfair Exchange  1.04  2.67  1.04
```

Comment: I need the source, I suppose that every odds came from the bookmakers url. I would know the bookmaker url of the match in the main url.

Comment: @luke You can find some links to bookmakers when you do `print(data['odds'])`

Comment: are just ads link of the bookmaker not link to the match

Comment: @luka betexplorer site has probably deals with these bookmakers and the bookmakers send them the odds via different channels.